# If $S$ is a Lebesgue measurable set then these two measures are equal.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let, $S$ be a Lebesgue measurable set. Then we let,
$$\lambda^*(S) = \inf\{\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|B_j|: S \subseteq \bigcup^{\infty}_{j=1}B_j ~ ,B_i ~ \textrm{is an open interval for } i \in \mathbb{N}\},$$
and we define:
$$ m(S) = \sup\{\lambda^{*}(F): F \subseteq S, ~ \textrm{where } F \textrm{ is closed} \}.$$
I wish to demonstrate that $\lambda^*(S) = m(S)$. Recall that every closed set is Lebesgue measurable. Let, $\epsilon > 0$. Since $S$ is Lebesgue measurable, we know that there exists a closed set $F_{\epsilon}$ such that $F \subseteq S$, and:
$$ \lambda^*(S-F_{\epsilon}) \le \epsilon \implies \lambda^*(S) - \lambda^*(F_{\epsilon}) \le \epsilon.$$
By definition, $\lambda^{*}(F_{\epsilon}) \le m(S).$ Thus,
$$\lambda^{*}(S) - m(S) \le \epsilon \implies \lambda^*(S) \le \epsilon  ~ + ~ m(S).$$
Since $\epsilon $ was arbitrary, we can conclude that:
$$\lambda^{*}(S) \le m(S).$$
By definition of outer measure, there exists a $S \subseteq \bigcup^{\infty}_{j=1}B_j$ such that:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|B_j| \le \lambda^*(S) + \epsilon.$$
We have that,
$$m(S) \le \sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|B_j|,$$
because $\forall F \subseteq S$ such that $F$ is closed, $\lambda^{*}(F) \le\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|B_j| $. Hence,
$$m(S) \le \lambda^{*}(S) + \epsilon \implies m(S) = \lambda^{*}(S).$$

Does my proof look good, any mistakes? Thanks.

Comment: I think your definition of $\lambda^{\ast}$ is not correct.  It should be the $\inf$ across all such covers, shouldn't it?  Similarly, shouldn't $m$ be defined as the $\sup$ across all suitable $F$?

Comment: You are missing $\inf$.

Comment: Thanks, added those in there.